# Query Android's contacts without Google's "Other Contacts"

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm currently developing an android app that accesses the `Conatacts` and presents them on a `ListFragment`. Therefore I'm using a customized `CursorAdapter` and a `LoaderManager`. This works perfectly fine.

However, if android is synchronized with an Google account all of Google's "Other Contacts" are shown in my `ListFragment`. To these "Other Contacts" you have replied or wrote an email to but you have never added them to Google's "My Contacts". The reason you may have never seen them before is that they won't be visible on android's address book as long as your are specifically not searching for them.

After doing some research I realized that Google's "Other Contacts" are missing the `Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` flag compared to the Google's "My Contacts". So I simply added a selection to my CursorLoader (`Contacts.IS_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'"`) and came to realize that all Contacts entries stored on the phone or the sim card are missing in my `ListFragment` because they also lack the `Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` flag.

Now it gets tricky. The `RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE` hold the information whether it is stored on the phone (vnd.sec.contact.phone), the sim (vnd.sec.contacts.sim) or comes from a Google account (vnd.google). Anyway, it is not possible to create a query that uses the information `Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` and `RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE` at the same time.

Am I missing something here? There must be a way since it is implemented on android's address book.